# Command line parsing in argc/argv

Tags: c, command-line, argv, getopt, argc

I have the following code:

```
void parse(char *commandLine) {
    int rc = 0;
    int argc = 0;
    char *cmdLine;
    char *argv[MAX_ARGS];
    filename = NULL;
    stdoutFilename = NULL;
    stderrFilename = NULL;
    cmdLine = strdup(commandLine);
    char *param = strtok(cmdLine, " ");
    while (param && argc < MAX_ARGS) {
        argv[argc++] = param;
        param = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", argv[argc-1]);
    }
    free(cmdLine);
    scanOptions(argc, argv);
    printf("Filename %s\n", filename);
```

...

and

```
void scanOptions(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c ;
    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "Df:e:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'D': __debug = 1; break;
            case 'f': filename = strdup(optarg); break;
            case 'o': stdoutFilename = strdup(optarg); break;
            case 'e': stderrFilename = strdup(optarg); break;
            default: fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
        }
    }
}
```

filename, `stdoutFilename` and `stderrFilename` are *global* variables.
If I call the parse method as:

```
parse("-ftest/testfile.txt") the variable filename is not set and the call to 
printf("Filename %s\n", filename); prints "Filename (null)".
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: @nos as I understood OP need `testfile.txt` out of `"-ftest/testfile.txt"` thats why I said to breal using `/`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No. Command line arguments are seperated with spaces, for getopt() to work, you'll need to split the string similar to what a shell would do. (which is on whitespace)

Comment: @nos well I am not sure! :(

Comment: My idea was to buil argc and argv as if they are build when main is called so to use scanOptions. I know that scanOptions works if I pass it argv and argc used for main.

Comment: should there be a space after "-f"?

Comment: also, can you give everything printed, just to help clarify?

Comment: No...getopt should work also without spaces (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things wrong, that may or may not be the cause of your problem:

**Use of freed memory**

```
free(cmdLine);
scanOptions(argc, argv);
```

You can't free the cmdLine here, since your strtok() calls will assign pointers inside cmdLine to your argv. free() it after scanOptions() , though if you save any optarg pointers directly, they will point into space that you have free()'d - you use strdup() so youre safe in your case.

**Resetting getopt()**

If you have called getopt previously, you need to reset some of its variables so it can scan again, (see the getopt manpage for an explanation). You need to do:

```
optind = 0;
```

**Wrong index in argv**
The first index in argv is by convention the program name, not any program arguments.
So make sure your argv[0] isn't any of your arguments. But it needs to be a valid string and not e.g. a NULL pointer.

argv[1] should be the first argument.

**Add a sentiel to argv**

The traditional argv of main() ends with a NULL pointer, your emulated argv should too.
After the while loop, do

```
argv[argc] = NULL;
```

Comment: The error was to call free(cmdLine) before doing scanOptions. Then I also added a line with argv[argc++] = strdup("dummy"); before pushing items in argv so to have a fake argv[0]. Thanks.

Comment: argv[argc++] = "dummy"...no strdup is required;

Answer (score 2):

`getopt(3)` considers `argv[0]` to be the program name and so will only parse arguments for `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc...

To make it work, init `argc` to `1` in `parse()` while you build your temporary array:

```
int argc = 1;
```

Comment: why was this downvoted?  seemed to find the problem, and do so first.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments to your post. But i would like to know the following:-

why cant you call scanOptions() directly from Main.

scanOptions(argc, argv);

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not answer the question.

Comment: Because there is no main...this is part of a dll and I would like the parse method to be called with a command line like the one used for main.

Comment: @alk, Comment feature seems to be disabled in my account.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you might like to add this fact to your answer so I can un-downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

`getopt` expects the parameters to be stored in `argv` from index `1` on.

`argv[0]` by conventions is used by the program's name.

So you might like to change your code from:

```
int argc = 0;
```

to be:

```
int argc = 1;
```

Comment: did you downvote the other answer that said this?  your answer and the downvote appeared at the same time, to me.

Comment: @andrewcooke: No, I upvoted it, as it seemed correct to me, obviously ... ;-) This is not a fight here, isn't it? S-/

Answer (score 0):

I add the correct piece of code for reference:

```
    char *param = strtok(cmdLine, " ");
    argv[argc++] = "dummy";
    while (param && argc < MAX_ARGS) {
        argv[argc++] = param;
        param = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    scanOptions(argc, argv);
    free(cmdLine);
```

The solution is to add argv[argc++] = "dummy"; to fill argv[0] and to call free(cmdLine) after scanOptions.

Comment: Although this seems to be correct, an explaination would be fine and whould improve this answer. Also: what is the call to `pthread_attr_init()` for?

Comment: The call to pthread_attr_init...is for something else, which is not related to the problem...The solution is to add argv[argc++] = "dummy"; to fill argv[0] and to call free(cmdLine) after scanOptions.

Answer (score -1):

This is far to complicated and error phrone. You cannot maintain this. Use boost::program_options instead.

It will look like:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

boost::program_options::variables_map vars;

po::options_description options("Command line options");

options.add_options()
    ("help", "display this help message and exit")
    ("in", po::value<std::string>()->default_value("file1.txt"), "input file")
    ("out", "output file");

po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options), vars);
po::notify(vars);

std::string infile = vars["in"].as<std::string>();
```

Comment: The OP is about C so Boost can't help here.